# How do I step into the Android source files for debugging via eclipse

Tags: android, debugging, eclipse-indigo

I just upgraded to eclipse 3.7 (indigo) and have an odd error running my android 3.2 app.
Looks like I will need to step into the Android Tools sdk (rev 13) to debug it.

What is the easiest way to setup the debugger to step into the sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this interesting:
http://blog.michael-forster.de/2008/12/view-android-source-code-in-eclipse.html

I had used it once to fix my problem.

Comment: v. nice;  I don't have python so the whole moving into a source directory part would be hard.  Do you know of any pre-packaged zip files for android 3.2?